# IF, ELIF, ELSE ArcPro How to calculate a field

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to calculate a field based on another field.  If my ELcorrect field is a certain number then the Part field needs to be either Drift1, Drift2, Drift3 etc or else Ramp for all other values.  Here is my code:

```
def TheCoder(code):
  if code==-266:
    var="Drift1"
  elif code==-265:
    var="Drift2"
  elif code==-262:
    var="Drift3"
  elif code==-251:
    var="Drift4"
  elif code==-250:
    var="Drift5"
  else:
    var="Ramp"
  return var
```

With the Part=TheCoder(!ELcorrect!)

It runs successfully but it doesn't populate anything.  So not sure what exactly it is doing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve]. I also recommend that you take some time to read or refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by not populating anything. Is it that you are not getting a return?

You could try the following code:

```
def TheCoder(code):
    if code==-266:
        return "Drift1"
    elif code==-265:
        return "Drift2"
    elif code==-262:
        return "Drift3"
    elif code==-251:
        return "Drift4"
    elif code==-250:
        return "Drift5"
    else:
        return "Ramp"
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: It worked.  I simply replaced the var= with return and it populated the field. Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!!!!! :-)